# How to transfer input box data to a complex structure JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I use jQuery get a JSON string from a API. I want to display it and change some field and PUT back to the API. But it seems to hard to gather information from input box and put it into right field.
Here is the json structure:

```
{
  "economicStatus": "",
  "title1": "",
  "migrantEducation": "",
  "disability": {
    "status": "",
    "section504Status": "",
    "primaryDisability": {
      "code": "",
      "codesetName": "",
      "item": "object",
      "otherCodeList": [
        {
          "value": "",
          "codesetName": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "awaitingInitialIDEAEvaluation": ""
  },
  "giftedTalented": "",
  "firstNationalEnrollment": "",
  "alertMessageList": [
    {
      "message": "object",
      "messageType": ""
    }
  ],
  "medicalAlertMessageList": [
    {
      "message": "",
      "severity": ""
    }
  ],
  "projectedGraduationYear": "",
  "onTimeGraduationYear": "",
  "graduationDate": "",
  "economicDisadvantage": "",
  "otherIdList": [
    {
      "idValue": "object",
      "idType": {
        "code": "",
        "codesetName": "",
        "item": "object",
        "otherCodeList": [
          {
            "value": "",
            "codesetName": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "nameRole": "",
    "actualNameOfRecord": {
      "prefix": "",
      "familyNameFirst": "",
      "preferredFamilyNameFirst": "",
      "givenName": "",
      "middleName": "",
      "familyName": "",
      "preferredFamilyName": "",
      "preferredGivenName": "",
      "fullName": "",
      "sortName": "",
      "suffix": ""
    }
  },
  "phoneNumberList": [
    {
      "number": "",
      "extension": "",
      "phoneNumberType": {
        "code": "",
        "codesetName": "",
        "item": "object",
        "otherCodeList": [
          {
            "value": "",
            "codesetName": ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "listedStatus": ""
    }
  ],
  "emailList": [
    {
      "emailAddress": "",
      "emailType": {
        "code": "",
        "codesetName": "",
        "item": "object",
        "otherCodeList": [
          {
            "value": "",
            "codesetName": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "localId": {
    "idValue": "object",
    "idType": {
      "code": "",
      "codesetName": "",
      "item": "object",
      "otherCodeList": [
        {
          "value": "",
          "codesetName": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "externalId": {
    "idValue": "object",
    "idType": {
      "code": "",
      "codesetName": "",
      "item": "object",
      "otherCodeList": [
        {
          "value": "",
          "codesetName": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "addressRefIdList": [
    {
      "value": "",
      "addressRole": ""
    }
  ],
  "otherNameList": [
    {
      "nameRole": "",
      "otherName": {
        "prefix": "",
        "familyNameFirst": "",
        "preferredFamilyNameFirst": "",
        "givenName": "",
        "middleName": "",
        "familyName": "",
        "preferredFamilyName": "",
        "preferredGivenName": "",
        "fullName": "",
        "sortName": "",
        "suffix": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "demographics": {
    "birthDateVerification": "",
    "sexus": "",
    "birthDate": "",
    "subregionOfBirth": {
      "code": "",
      "codesetName": "",
      "item": "object",
      "otherCodeList": [
        {
          "value": "",
          "codesetName": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "stateProvinceOfBirth": {
      "code": "",
      "codesetName": "",
      "item": "object",
      "otherCodeList": [
        {
          "value": "",
          "codesetName": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "placeOfBirth": "",
    "countryOfBirth": {
      "code": "",
      "codesetName": "",
      "item": "object",
      "otherCodeList": [
        {
          "value": "",
          "codesetName": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "countryArrivalDate": "",
    "citizenshipStatus": "",
    "languageProficiency": "",
    "dwellingArrangement": "",
    "maritalStatus": "",
    "ethnicityList": [
      {
        "code": "",
        "codesetName": "",
        "item": "object",
        "otherCodeList": [
          {
            "value": "",
            "codesetName": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "languageList": [
      {
        "languageCode": {
          "code": "",
          "codesetName": "",
          "item": "object",
          "otherCodeList": [
            {
              "value": "",
              "codesetName": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "languageType": "",
        "dialect": ""
      }
    ],
    "countryOfResidency": {
      "code": "",
      "codesetName": "",
      "item": "object",
      "otherCodeList": [
        {
          "value": "",
          "codesetName": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "countryOfCitizenshipList": [
      {
        "code": "",
        "codesetName": "",
        "item": "object",
        "otherCodeList": [
          {
            "value": "",
            "codesetName": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "electronicIdList": [
    {
      "idValue": "object",
      "idType": {
        "code": "",
        "codesetName": "",
        "item": "object",
        "otherCodeList": [
          {
            "value": "",
            "codesetName": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "refId": ""
}
```

And here is a sample data I get back from API, with some field are null:

```
{
  "disability": null,
  "economicStatus": null,
  "migrantEducation": null,
  "title1": null,
  "alertMessageList": null,
  "medicalAlertMessageList": null,
  "projectedGraduationYear": null,
  "onTimeGraduationYear": null,
  "graduationDate": null,
  "giftedTalented": null,
  "economicDisadvantage": null,
  "firstNationalEnrollment": null,
  "otherIdList": [
    {
      "idType": {
        "code": "AuthenticationUsername",
        "item": null,
        "otherCodeList": null,
        "codesetName": "HMH.OtherId"
      },
      "idValue": "ChK@username-60ty"
    },
    {
      "idType": {
        "code": "HMOF UserName",
        "item": null,
        "otherCodeList": null,
        "codesetName": "HMH.OtherId"
      },
      "idValue": "ChK@username-60ty.arda.stu"
    },
    {
      "idType": {
        "code": "Role",
        "item": null,
        "otherCodeList": null,
        "codesetName": "HMH.OtherId"
      },
      "idValue": "learner"
    }
  ],
  "addressRefIdList": null,
  "name": null,
  "localId": {
    "idType": {
      "code": "LASID",
      "item": null,
      "otherCodeList": null,
      "codesetName": "HMH.LocalId"
    },
    "idValue": "79800003270ABCKrtg12"
  },
  "externalId": {
    "idType": {
      "code": "SASID",
      "item": null,
      "otherCodeList": null,
      "codesetName": "HMH.ExternalId"
    },
    "idValue": "NULL"
  },
  "electronicIdList": null,
  "otherNameList": null,
  "demographics": null,
  "phoneNumberList": null,
  "emailList": null,
  "refId": "3329962f-18ab-415f-addb-132cbe613d68"
}
```

Is there a simple way to change the fields in a page using input box? I try to create as many input boxes as needed and name them and associate them with corresponding JSON field... But it seems to tedious and can not update array dynamically.

Comment: Which fields do you want to change in a page? what page?

Comment: I want to create a "Profile" page, show the information GET from the API and provide input boxes for users to change any field. So most fields are supposed to be changed in the "Profile" page.